# How to Create A Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am writing a program that monitors and records usage time of foreground applications and saves them in a SQL database. I then want to retrieve the data from previous days and compile it all together into a stacked bar chart. Here, the x-axis will have the different days over which usage was recorded, and the various stacks in each bar will represent each app that was used.

In my program, I created 2 tables, one to record each day's app usage (with each new day's data having a different primary key id), and another table to record the primary key for each day.

Table 1:

| _id | Application | usage_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Google Chrome | 245.283942928347 |
| 0 | Finder | 123.384234239734 |
| 0 | PyCharm | 100.484829432934 |
| 1 | PyCharm | 1646.46116232872 |
| 1 | SQLiteStudio | 160.25696277618408 |
| 1 | Google Chrome | 1756.8145654201508 |
| 1 | Microsoft Teams | 150.2583293914795 |

Table 2:

| Date | daily_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-18 07:25:25.376734 | 0 |
| 2021-07-18 07:27:57.419574 | 1 |

Within my stacked bar chart program, I have come up with this code to refine the data to put into the stacked bar chart:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('daily_usage_monitor.sqlite', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

all_app_data = conn.execute('SELECT all_usage_information.date, monitor.application, monitor.usage_time '
                            'FROM all_usage_information '
                            'INNER JOIN monitor ON all_usage_information.daily_id = monitor._id '
                            'ORDER BY all_usage_information.date, monitor.usage_time ASC').fetchall()

for date, app, usage_time in all_app_data:
    print(f'{date} - {app}: {usage_time}')
conn.close()

daily_data = {}

# Create nested dictionary - key = each date, value = dictionary of different apps & their time usage durations
for date, app, time in all_app_data:
    conditions = [date not in daily_data, app != 'loginwindow']
    if all(conditions):
        daily_data[date] = {app: time}
    elif not conditions[0] and conditions[1]:
        daily_data[date].update({app: time})

print(daily_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING

total_time = 0
# Club any applications that account for <5% of total time into 1 category called 'Other'
for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
    total_time = sum(time for app, time in app_usages.items())

    refined_data = {}
    for key, value in app_usages.items():
        if value/total_time < 0.05:
            refined_data['Others'] = refined_data.setdefault('Others', 0) + value
        else:
            refined_data[key] = value
    daily_data[date] = refined_data

print(daily_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING

# Add key:value pairs initializing apps to 0 which are either used in past and never used again
# or used in future but not in past
used_apps = set()
counter = 0
for date, app_usages in reversed(daily_data.items()):
    for app, time in app_usages.items():
        used_apps.add(app)
    counter += 1
    if counter != 1:
        for used_app in used_apps:
            if used_app not in app_usages.keys():
                app_usages[used_app] = 0

used_apps = set()
counter = 0
for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
    for app, time in app_usages.items():
        used_apps.add(app)
    counter += 1
    if counter != 1:
        for used_app in used_apps:
            if used_app not in app_usages.keys():
                app_usages[used_app] = 0
print(daily_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING

# Takes the nested dictionary and breaks it into a labels list and a dictionary with apps & time usages for each day
# Sorts data so it can be used to create composite bar chart
final_data = {}
labels = []
for date, app_usages in daily_data.items():
    labels.append(date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    for app, time in app_usages.items():
        # time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)   # TODO: CHECK WHAT TO DO
        if app not in final_data:
            final_data[app] = [time]
        else:
            final_data[app].append(time)
print(final_data)
final_data = dict(sorted(final_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

print(final_data)   # TODO: REMOVE AFTER TESTING
```

This processing is giving this output:
{'Google Chrome': [245.283942928347, 1756.8145654201508], 'Finder': [123.3842342397347, 0], 'PyCharm': [100.4848294329348, 1646.46116232872], 'Others': [0, 310.5152921676636]}

And then, in order to create the stacked bar chart, this is the code I wrote:

```
width = 0.5
counter = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, value in final_data.items():
    if counter == 0:
        ax.bar(labels, value, width=width, label=key)
    else:
        ax.bar(labels, value, width=width, bottom=bottom, label=key)
    bottom = value
    counter += 1
ax.set_ylabel('Time usage on applications')
ax.set_xlabel('Dates (DD-MM-YYYY)')
ax.set_title('Time Usage Trend')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, this is the output I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, the 1st bar has an overlap, the Google Chrome bar is missing from the 2nd stacked bar, and the Finder bar is extremely small, even though it is not that small comparative to the other data.

Any ideas on how I could fix this stacked bar chart? Would also appreciate suggestions on how to refine the data processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Troubleshooting matplotlib stacked bar charts

It looks like your problem is the for loop. You are iterating through the keys and values, and plotting the values each iteration.

```
for key, value in final_data.items():
    print(key, value)

Google Chrome [245.283942928347, 1756.8145654201508]
Finder [123.3842342397347, 0]
PyCharm [100.4848294329348, 1646.46116232872]
Others [0, 310.5152921676636]
```

What you're intending to do is plot each LABEL per iteration. You could change your for loop, but I'd recommend just putting your dict into a pandas dataframe and using [pandas DataFrame.plot.bar(stacked=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#other-plots). It takes a lot of the hassle of setting 'bottom' or 'left' for stacked bar charts.

```
final_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Google Chrome': [245.283942928347, 1756.8145654201508], 
    'Finder': [123.3842342397347, 0], 
    'PyCharm': [100.4848294329348, 1646.46116232872], 
    'Others': [0, 310.5152921676636]}
)

final_data.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It's working now, thank you! Do you have any suggestions for how I could improve the performance of my data processing though?